# Post HTML form data to CSV and create email notification using ASP

Tags: html, asp-classic

unfortunately I am forced to use ASP for this particular task. I need my form to post its data to a CSV and then send an email notifying the client. Now the first bit I already have working (posting the data to a CSV file) but its the email notification that is getting me, as I have no idea how or what to incorporate into my current code in order for this to happen.

Here is a link to the form in question:
http://dev.brandspank.co.za/form/index.html

And below is my ASP code:

```
    <% option explicit

dim objFSO, objTXT, lines, newRecord, filePath, fieldNames, x, fullText, nLine %>
<h1>Form inputs posted:</h1>
<%

for each x in request.form
   response.write x & ": " & Replace(request.form(x), ",","-") & "<br />" & vbNewLine
next

'set filepath for plain text db.  This neds to be the absolute path of file
filePath = "\form\myCSVdb.csv"
set objFSO = server.createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if (objFSO.fileExists(filePath))=true then
   set objTXT = objFSO.openTextFile(filePath, 1) 'opens a text file for
   ' reading, true means it will create the file if not already there
   fullText = trim(objTXT.readall)
   lines = split(fullText, vbNewLine) 'lines is now an array, each item is
    ' one line of the db file.this could now be used to list the entire db
    ' table, notice next 3 commented out lines
    ' for each x in lines
    '    response.write lines(x)
    ' next

   objTXT.close
   set objTXT = nothing

   if trim(lines(0)) = "" then fullText = ""
else
   fullText = ""
end if %>

<h1>added to the db:</h1>

<%
if fullText <> "" then 'there are already field names in the db,
   ' so put the new line in the same order
   set objTXT = objFSO.openTextFile(filePath, 8, True) 'opens the text file for
   '  appending
   response.write "(fields in the database: " & lines(0) & ")<br />" & vbNewLine
   'split the first line, which had field names into an array -fieldNames-
   fieldNames = split(lines(0), ",")

   response.write "field values entered:<br />" & vbNewLine
   for each x in fieldNames
      if x <> "" then
         nLine = nLine & Replace(request.form(x), ",","-") & "," 
         'adds each form input to a string

         response.write x & ": " & Replace(request.form(x), ",","-") & "<br />" & vbNewLine
      end if
   next
   nLine = left(nLine, len(nLine)-1)
   'removes trailing comma

   objTXT.writeLine nLine

else 'there isn't anything in the textfile yet, so put in the field names first
   set objTXT = objFSO.openTextFile(filePath, 2, True) 'opens the text file for
   '  writing
   response.write "field names enterd:<br />" & vbNewLine

   for each x in request.form
      if Replace(lcase(x), ","," ") <> "submit" then 'or you will have a "submit" field in your db
         'of course, if your submit button is named something else, that should
         'be the name xcluded here

         nLine = nLine & x & ","
         'adds each form input name to a string which will become th first line of
         'the db, the line which shows field names

         response.write x & "<br />" & vbNewLine
      end if
   next
   nLine = left(nLine, len(nLine)-1)
   'remove trailing comma

   objTXT.write nLine
   objTXT.write vbNewLine
   nLine = ""

   response.write "field values entered:<br />" & vbNewLine
   for each x in request.form
      if lcase(x) <> "submit" then
         nLine = nLine & Replace(request.form(x), ",","-") & "," 
         'adds each form input to a string

         response.write Replace(request.form(x), ",","-") & "<br />" & vbNewLine
      end if
   next
   nLine = left(nLine, len(nLine)-1)
   'remove trailing comma

   objTXT.write nLine
   objTXT.write vbNewLine
end if
objTXT.close
%>

<% response.redirect "thankyou.html" %>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put pretty much everything you need here: 
[www.oceanmedia.net/files/2014-06-form-process.zip](http://www.oceanmedia.net/files/2014-06-form-process.zip)
Included:

> - form_process. asp
> - i_fn_email_cdo.asp
> - i_check_security.asp
> - i_odbc.asp
> - i_fn_clean.asp
> - i_fn_dirty.asp

Oh and the text file part:

```
<%
Dim fso, f
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Open the file for reading
Set f = fso.CreateTextFile(s_path & "/" & s_file_being_created, True)
f.Write(m)
f.Close
Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: I am going to download this tonight! (Just at work now) and give it a bash! Thank you so much i really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hey ScotterMonkey, once again thanks for your help thus far! I set up all the ASP files on my server and have the html form process linking to "form_process.asp" but I see the following error upon submit: http://dev.brandspank.co.za/stack/form_process.asp

Comment: The error message is telling you that in the i_odbc.asp file, it points to a database. You need to tell it to point to YOUR database.

Comment: Ok i thought as much, on which line exactly?

Comment: That is something you really should be able to figure out on your own because it points to a file. I want to tell you the answer but that would impede you learning a very basic and important lesson. The error message really did give you all you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't yet have comment privileges, so this will be a comment disguised as an answer: the specifics will depend upon how your web server is configured in terms of email, but assuming it is somewhat current, you will probably be using CDOSYS to do so, and here is a link to a very basic intro: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp

You've navigated the FileSystemObject, so you'll probably find this fairly straightforward once you get the details right on your mail server.